# How to find all Events with a specific URL in the description?

Tags: rest-api, rest

I keep getting a MALFORMED_SEARCH error for this `find` using the REST API:

```
FIND {"http://www.google.com"} IN ALL FIELDS RETURNING Event
```

After removing one character type at a time, it seems that the colon seems to be throwing the MALFORMED_SEARCH error. How can I search for the full string including the colon?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As per this doc: http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/soql_sosl/Content/sforce_api_calls_sosl_find.htm#i1423049

> The following characters are reserved: **? & | ! { } [ ] ( ) ^ ~ * **:** \ "**
>   ' + -
>
> Reserved characters, if specified in a text search, must be escaped
>   (preceded by the backslash \ character) in order to be properly
>   interpreted.

try:

```
http\://www.google.com
```